# php CI- A Database Error Occurred

Tags: php

I got this error with php CI:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''%blackhat%)ORDER BY mid DESC' at line 5
>
> SELECT COUNT mid, mtitle, mtitle_identifier, msinopsis, mauthors, mdirectors, mproducers FROM srt_movie WHERE (mtitle LIKE '%blackhat%' OR msinopsis LIKE '%blackhat%' OR mauthors LIKE '%blackhat%' OR mdirectors LIKE '%blackhat%' OR mproducers LIKE '%blackhat%)ORDER BY mid DESC
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/sorot/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Here is my syntax in model:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT mid, mtitle, mtitle_identifier, msinopsis, mauthors, mdirectors, mproducers FROM srt_movie WHERE (";
        while (list($key,$val) = each($rwords))

        {
            if($val <> " " AND strlen($val) > 0)
            {
                $sql1 .="mtitle LIKE '%$val%' OR
                        msinopsis LIKE '%$val%' OR
                        mauthors LIKE '%$val%' OR
                        mdirectors LIKE '%$val%' OR
                        mproducers LIKE '%$val%' OR";
            }
        }   
        $sql1 = substr($sql1,0,(strlen($sql1)-4));
        $sql1 .=")";
        $sql1 .="ORDER BY mid DESC";
        if(! is_null($limit))
        {
            $sql1 .="LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offsset";
        }

        //lakukan query
        $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1);
        $result['movie_num'] = $query1->num_rows();
        if($result ['movie_num'] >0)
        {
            $result['movie'] = $this->mark_up_result($words,$query->result());
        }
        else
        {
            return " .";
        }
        return $result;

    }
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Syntax error, `%blackhat%'` is missing a single quote at the end.

Comment: oh yeah thank you, i added the space after the qoute the it working.